# Understanding the definition of $C^r$-homotopy of functions on manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

The book "Manifolds and Differential Geometry" by Jeffrey Lee gives the following definition:

> **Definition:** Let $f_0: X \rightarrow Y$ and $f_1: X \rightarrow Y$ be $C^r$-maps. A $C^r$-homotopy from $f_0$ to $f_1$ is a $C^r$-map $H: X \times \left[ 0, 1 \right] \rightarrow Y$ such that for all $x \in X$, we have $H \left( x, 0 \right) = f_0 \left( x \right)$ and $H \left( x, 1 \right) = f_1 \left( x \right)$.

I have trouble understanding what is meant by $H$ being a $C^r$-function? Clearly, the definition assumes that $X$ and $Y$ have a differential structure (otherwise, the first statement does not make sense). However, to make sense of the fact that $H$ is a differentiable map, we must have a differentiable structure on $X \times \left[ 0, 1 \right]$. Now, purely speaking in terms of manifolds, $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$ is not (simply) a manifold; it is a manifold with boundary. How do we define differentiability in this case? Do we leave out the boundary of the manifold as we do in the case of functions with real domain?

Comment: Indeed, this is differentiability in the sense of a manifold with boundary. If $\varphi\colon U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a chart of $X$, then we can look at $H\vert_{U\times[0,1]}\circ(\varphi\times\mathrm{id}_{[0,1]})^{-1}\colon\varphi(U)\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$. Now, $\varphi(U)\times[0,1]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The function $H$ is $C^r$ if all these maps are $C^r$, where being $C^r$ on an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ means that each point has an open neighborhood (in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ on which the function extends to a $C^r$ function in the usual sense.